# Dejar pegar un número en un input con ciertas validaciones con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo podría hacer que yo al momento de copiar un número de 17 dígitos con un punto antes de los dos últimos dígitos, ejemplo: (123655012978541.59) uno pueda pegarlo al input?, pero sí por ejemplo este tiene menos o más de esta cantidad no deje pegarlo o sí tiene letras tampoco lo deje pegar. Ejemplo: esto **no** lo deje copiar: (154dfg89q2), o (12054.89602.9)

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es algo como una llave de validación?

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que crees un If que reconozca el valor del campo (si va a dejar pegar el número) pero si es mayor a `x` cantidad, entonces que no permita continuar y que muestre un mensaje que diga "este número no es válido" o algo por el estilo.

Comment: ¿es un para un input en html? Porque puedes restringir que el input sea númerico, con un valor máximo y mínimo y dos decimales.

Comment: Puedes utilizar un plugin como [jqueryvalidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)
Supongo que se puede crear una mascara para lo que intentas hacer

Comment: Podrías utilizar Regex, aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo: `([0-9]{15})+\.([0-9]{2})`

Comment: De todos modos no necesitas jquery, con un pattern lo puedes hacer:
__<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{17}\.[0-9]{2}">__

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Me sirvió con el solo pattern.

Comment: Solo que hay un problema, al momento de uno inspeccionar el elemento y borrar el pattern me deja pegar cualquier cosa, ¿Como lo solucionaría?

Answer (score 1):

Es que ya hice algo como esto

```
 function validaNumero(e) {
                var val = jQuery(e.target).val().toString();
                console.log(val, val.indexOf("e"));
                if (val.indexOf("e") < 0) {
                    val = `${val.substr(0, val.length - 2)}.${val.substr(val.length - 2, 2)}`;
                console.log(val);
                    if (Number(val) > 0 && val.length == 18) {
                        jQuery(e.target).val(val);
                    } else {
                        jQuery(e.target).val("");
                    }
                } else {
                    jQuery(e.target).val("");
                    alert("Dato inválido para el campo JobID");
                }
            }
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('#txtJobID').change(validaNumero);
                jQuery('#txtJobID').keydown(validaNumero);
            });
```

Pero al momento de yo pegar el número correcto y cambiar de input se borran los datos.

Comment: esto sería mejor agregarlo a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar usar esta función, ya solo es que le adaptes que no rebase cierta cantidad:

**HTML:**

```
<body>  
   <input type="text" id="textBox" class="numericOnly" />  
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){  
                $(".numericOnly").bind('keypress',function(e){  
                          if(e.keyCode == '9' || e.keyCode == '16'){  
                                return;  
                           }  
                           var code;  
                           if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;  
                           else if (e.which) code = e.which;   
                           if(e.which == 46)  
                                return false;  
                           if (code == 8 || code == 46)  
                                return true;  
                           if (code < 48 || code > 57)  
                                return false;  
                     }  
                );  
                $(".numericOnly").bind("paste",function(e) {  
                     e.preventDefault();  
                });  
                $(".numericOnly").bind('mouseenter',function(e){  
                      var val = $(this).val();  
                      if (val!='0'){  
                           val=val.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "")  
                           $(this).val(val);  
                      }  
                });  
           });
```